# Aspect ratio equivalent for Android?

Tags: android, layout, aspect-ratio

I would like to add a view with an leading/trailing margin of 12dp and an aspect ratio of 4:1 of the screen width.
Coming from an iOS background, I would this to get that result:

[image]

Now I want to do the same with Android, and I'm only stuck with the aspect ratio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        <!-- android:layout_height="{what to do here?}" -->
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:background="@color/my_blue_color" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What do I have to change here about the view's height to get the expected ratio?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using ConstraintLayout

Add Dependency first

```
dependencies {
    implementation'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

Here is an example

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.burhanrashid52.unittestsample.MainActivity">


            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:4"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


      </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

Ypu need to use ConstraintLayout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```