# Android: Keep view's aspect ratio by using portrait and landscape mode

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a view with a fixed ratio. I took the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49811826/aspect-ratio-equivalent-for-android)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,3:4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Works in portrait mode but in landscape mode it breaks out of the screen.

Portrait: https://i.ibb.co/H72gP7v/Portrait.jpg

Landscape: https://i.ibb.co/2kdPVK7/Landscape.jpg

Is there a way to keep a given aspect ratio in both modes (portrait and landscape)?

Comment: Could you provide screenshot in both portrait and landscape mode, so it is more understandable

Comment: @user7893488, it's advisable to create a landscape variant of your layout while ensuring that you set the `android:layout_height` attribute to `match_parent`. You will maintains a consistent aspect ratio across different screen orientations.

Comment: That was one of my ideas as well, but I thought that there would be a better solution.